# How to write factory functions that adhere to the 'open closed principle'

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been researching the use of factory functions as an alternative to constructors in JavaScript. Most of my research has stemmed from the information provided by Eric Elliot in his blog posts such as:

http://ericleads.com/2012/09/stop-using-constructor-functions-in-javascript

Whilst I agree with most of what's said here I do miss having the automatic initialization aspect of constructors so I wanted to implement something similar within my factory function:

```
var myFactory = function (options) {
    var inst = _.create({
        initialize : function (options) {
            var allowedProps = ['name', 'type'];

            this.options = options;
            _.extend(this, _.pick(options, allowedProps));
        },

        test : function () {
            if(this.type === 'alpha') {
              return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    })

    inst.initialize.call(inst, options);

    return inst;
};

var x = myFactory({ name : 'shiny', type : 'alpha' });
var y = myFactory({ name : 'happy', type : 'beta' });
```

1) Is this behavior itself just re-introducing some of the problems that come with constructors?

2) Am I violating the Open/Closed principle by extending the instance with 'options' within the initialize method? It's open for extension (it can be used as a prototype) but I can also modify the prototype itself through 'options'.

I've got a bad feeling about this pattern and feel like I should be giving ultimate control of initialization to the consumer. It's heavily inspired by Backbone's method of extension which relies on constructors.

Further reading:

https://tsherif.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/constructors-are-bad-for-javascript/

Comment: There's a much bigger problem with your pattern actually: You are creating new prototype objects on every `myFactory` invocations. Which means that your methods are not shared. You should store the prototype object from which you `_.create()` your instances statically, outside of the `myFactory`. Maybe even accessible as `myFactory.prototype`?

Comment: I agree. I think you're referring to 'examplars'? Store the prototype/exemplar outside and let factory functions do different things with it? Thanks for your answer by the way. Very helpful.

Comment: I must confess I've never heard the term "exemplar". But yes, the prototype should be stored separately instead of being recreated every time.

Comment: I think Eric Elliot might have coined the term in this article: http://ericleads.com/2013/02/fluent-javascript-three-different-kinds-of-prototypal-oo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this behavior itself just re-introducing some of the problems that come with constructors?

No, altough it is re-introducing constructors. Just swap `initialize` for `constructor` and you'd have nearly the same result. Only with very unidiomatic syntax :-)

> 2) Am I violating the Open/Closed principle by extending the instance with 'options' within the initialize method?

No, the point that the article makes how constructors would break the open/closed principle was that for swapping them out with a different factory you had to remove `new` all over your code (which in fact you dont). But if you extend your class, you will not have to change its invocations.

> I've got a bad feeling about this pattern and feel like I should be giving ultimate control of initialization to the consumer.

Well, if you want to do that just remove the initializer and let the consumer do the `extend`:

```
var x = _.extend(myFactory(), { name : 'shiny', type : 'alpha' });
var y = _.extend(myFactory(), { name : 'happy', type : 'beta' });
```